# Script to copy remote files based on file name and date comparison of their names

Tags: shell-script, centos, filenames, scp

I have a directory with these files:

> app_conf.jboss.app_hostname_20160913_191141.tgz
> app_conf.jboss.app_hostname_20160913_194047.tgz
> app_conf.provider.app_hostname_20160913_194044.tgz
> app_conf.provider.app_hostname_20160928_071002.tgz
> app_conf.deployments.ear.app_hostname_20160913_194047.tgz
> app_conf.deployments.ear.app_hostname_20160915_071005.tgz
> app_conf.bin.jboss_cluster.app_hostname_20160913_194044.tgz
> app_conf.bin.jboss_cluster.app_hostname_20160913_194047.tgz
> app_conf.bin.conf.app_hostname_20160913_194043.tgz
> app_conf.bin.conf.app_hostname_20160913_194047.tgz

The files are varying only by date because could be exists multiple files with the same part of the name ("string_name"_YYMMDD_HHMMSS.tgz)

I need a script that only copy the last version of the file depending your type.

Example:

> string_name1_20160913_194047.tgz.
>
> string_name1_20160913_194043.tgz.

It shoul copy only string_name1_20160913_194047.tgz.

And do this for all the rest type of files...

For Now I'm copying manually:

```
scp username@host:/tmp/string_name1_20160913_194047.tgz /home/config/
```

Appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
cd /home/config && ssh user@host << \EOF | tar xpf -
zsh -c '
  cd /tmp || exit
  typeset -A seen; files=()
  for f (app_conf*_*_*.tgz(On)) {let '\''seen[${f%_*_*}]++'\'' || files+=($f)}
  tar cf - $files'
EOF
```

If `user`'s login shell on `host` is `zsh`, you can simplify it to:

```
cd /home/config && ssh user@host '
  cd /tmp || exit
  typeset -A seen; files=()
  for f (app_conf*_*_*.tgz(On)) {let '\''seen[${f%_*_*}]++'\'' || files+=($f)}
  tar cf - $files' | tar xpf -
```

The idea is that we process the list of files in reverse order (`(On)`) and select the file if the part of the file name before `_*_*` has not been seen.

The files are transferred using `tar` which also has the benefit of transferring all the files' meta-data.

(see [How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627474) for why we're using `let` instead of `((...))` here).

Comment: Hi Stéphane, Im searching and testing with zsh. Interesting!!.. Thanks..