# How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?

Tags: bash, security, zsh, ksh, associative-array

A few Bourne-like shells support associative arrays: `ksh93` (since 1993), `zsh` (since 1998), `bash` (since 2009), though with some differences in behaviour between the 3.

A common use is for counting occurrences of some strings.

However, I find that things like:

```
typeset -A count
(( count[$var]++ ))
```

Don't work for some values of `$var` and I hear it even constitutes an ***arbitrary command execution* vulnerability** if the contents of `$var` is or may be under the control of an attacker.

Why is that? What are the problematic values? And how do I work around it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that in a shell arithmetic expression, such as

- inside `$((...))` (POSIX),
- `((...))` (ksh/bash/zsh)
- array indices
- some arguments of some shell builtins
- operands of numeric comparison operators inside `[[...]]`

word expansions (`${param}`, `$((...))`, `$[...]`, `$(...)`, `` `...` ``, `${ ...; }`) are performed *first*, and then the resulting text is interpreted as an arithmetic expression.

In the case of `$((...))`, that's even a POSIX requirement.

That allows things like `op=+; echo "$(( 1 $op 2 ))"` to work, and that explains why `a=1+1; echo "$(($a * 2))"` outputs `3` instead of `4`, as it's the `1+1 * 2` expression that is evaluated.

That's also partly [why using unsanitised data in arithmetic expressions is a security vulnerability](/q/172103) in general.

What is easy to overlook is that it also applies in things like

```
(( assoc[$var]++ ))
```

Above, except in `ksh93` (**edit** and now bash 5.2+, see below), `$var` is expanded first, and the result interpreted.

That means that if `$var` contains `@` or `*`, then the `assoc[@]++` or `assoc[*]++` expressions are evaluated, and `@`/`*` have special meanings there. If `$var` is `x] + 2 + assoc[y`, that becomes `assoc[x] + 2 + assoc[y]`.

Now normally, in `$(( $var ))`, even if `$var` contains something like `$(reboot)`, there is no second round of expansion happening, `reboot` is not going to be run. But as already seen at [Security Implications of using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103), there's an exception if that appears inside `word[...]` to allow recursive expansion. At the root of the problem is an unfortunate *feature* of the Korn shell whereby if `var` contains an arithmetic expression, then in `$((var))` the arithmetic expression in `$var` is being evaluated, even recursively (like when `var2='var3 + 1' var='var2 + 1'`), something allowed, but not required by POSIX.

As that's extended to array members, that means that the contents of array indexes end up being evaluated recursively. So, if `$var` is `$(reboot)`, then `(( assoc[$var]++ ))` ends up calling `reboot`.

`ksh93` seems to have some level of work around to it, but only when `$var` doesn't contain `$` it seems. So, while ksh93 is OK with `var=']'`, `var='@'`, or `` var='`reboot`' ``, it's not with `$(reboot)`.

As an example, if we replace `reboot` with the harmless `uname>&2`:

```
$ var='1$(uname>&2)' ksh -c 'typeset -A a; (( a[$var]++ )); typeset -p a'
Linux
typeset -A a=([1]=1)
$ var='1$(uname>&2)' bash -c 'typeset -A a; (( a[$var]++ )); typeset -p a'
Linux
Linux
declare -A a=([1]="1" )
$ var='1$(uname>&2)' zsh -c 'typeset -A a; (( a[$var]++ )); typeset -p a'
Linux
Linux
typeset -A a=( [1]=1 )
```

The `uname` command does end up being run (twice in `bash` (<5.2) and `zsh`, I suppose once for getting the current value and the second time to perform the assignment).

In version 5.0, bash added a `assoc_expand_once` option which changes the behaviour:

```
$ var='1$(uname>&2)' bash -O assoc_expand_once -c 'typeset -A a; ((a[$var]++)); typeset -p a'
declare -A a=(["1\$(uname>&2)"]="1" )
```

is now OK, but it doesn't address the problems with `@`, `*`, or `]` characters, so it doesn't address the *arbitrary command execution* vulnerability:

```
$ var='x]+b[1$(uname>&2)' bash -O assoc_expand_once -c 'typeset -A a; ((a[$var]++)); typeset -p a'
Linux
declare -A a
```

(this time, `uname` is being run as part of the evaluation of a *plain* array (`b`) index evaluation).

The list of problematic characters varies with the shell. `$` is a problem for all three, `\`, `` ` ``, `[` and `]` are a problem for `bash` and `zsh`, `"`, `'` for `bash`. Same for the `@` and `*` and empty values. Also note that in some locales, the encoding of some characters do contain that of `\`, `` ` ``, `[` or `]` at least and could cause problems. How to escape those must be done differently in all three shells.

To work around it, one can do:

```
assoc[$var]=$(( ${assoc[$var]} + 1 ))
```

instead. That is:

1. do not perform an assignment to an associative array member *as part* of the arithmetic expression but only perform bare associative array member assignments. In other words, do not use the `=`, `++`, `--`, `+=`, `/=`... arithmetic operators with an associative array member as the target.
2. when referencing an associative array within an arithmetic expression, do not use `assoc[$var]`, but `${assoc[$var]}` (or `$assoc[$var]` in `zsh`), or `(${assoc[$var]})` if that's meant to contain an arithmetic expression instead of just a number.

But, as always the *value* of that associative array member must be under your control, preferably a plain number, and like for any other parameter expansion, it's preferable to put whitespace around them. For instance `((1 - $var))` is preferable to `((1-$var))` as the latter would cause problem for negative values (`((1--1))` causes a syntax error in some shells as that's the `--` operator applied to `1`.

Another caveat is that when `$var` is empty, in `(( 1 + var ))`, that `var` is still a token in the arithmetic expression syntax, and the corresponding value if `0`. But in `(( 1 + $var ))`, the arithmetic expression becomes `1 +` which is a syntax error (`(( $var + 1 ))` is OK though, as that becomes `+ 1`, invoking the unary `+` operator).

Other approaches with `bash` (5.1 or older and when the `assoc_expand_once` option is *not* enabled) or `zsh` (but not [`ksh93` which still has a problem with `]` and `\` characters](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/152)), are to delay the expansion until that second, recursive interpretation mentioned above.

- `(( assoc[\$var]++ ))`
- `let 'assoc[$var]++'` (make sure to use *single* quotes here)
- `incr='assoc[$var]++'; (($incr))` (or even `((incr))`)
- `((' assoc[$var]++ '))` or `(( assoc['$var']++ ))` (`bash` only).

Those have the advantage or preserving the exit status resulting from the arithmetic evaluation (*success* if non-zero), so one can do things like:

```
if (( assoc[\$var]++ )); then
  printf '%s\n' "$var was already seen"
fi
```

Now, that leaves one problem specific to the `bash` shell: `bash` associative arrays don't support empty keys. While `assoc[]=x` fails in both `bash` and `zsh` (not `ksh93`), `assoc[$var]` when `$var` is empty works in `zsh` or `ksh93` but not `bash`. Even `zsh`'s `assoc+=('' value)` now supported by bash-5.1 doesn't work in `bash`.

So if working with `bash` specifically and if an empty key is one of the possible values, the only option is to add a fixed prefix/suffix. So use for instance:

```
assoc[.$var]=$(( ${assoc[.$var]} + 1 ))
```

Or:

```
let 'assoc[.$var]++'
(( assoc[.\$var]++ ))
...
```

### 2023 edit

Most of those work arounds above no long work with bash-5.2.

In bash-5.2.21, `(( assoc[$var]++ ))` (for non-empty `$var`) and `(( assoc[.$var]++ ))` appear to be safe even if `$var` contains `]`, `\`, `*` or `@`.

They remain ACE vulnerabilities with  older versions.

The only approaches that work with both 5.2  and pre-5.2 versions seem to be:

- `let 'assoc[$var]++'`
- `assoc[$var]=$(( ${assoc[$var]} + 1 ))`
- `ref='assoc[$var]'; (( $ref++ ))`
- [@ormaaj's trick in the bash wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B.5B_-v_hash.5B.24key.5D_.5D.5D): `(( assoc${-+[}\$var]++ ))`.

Of which only the second works in all of ksh93, zsh and bash.

In particular, the `(( assoc[\$var] ))` approach that also works in zsh no longer works in bash-5.2.

Comment: If you replace `uname` with GNU's `date +'%T.%N'`, does it demonstrate more clearly the number of times that the unexpected command execution occurs? (Ref "_The uname command does end up being run (twice in bash and zsh, I suppose...)_")

Comment: `bash` is the wrong programming language for this.