# Unary test -v on an array element

Tags: bash, array, test

In bash, the conditional expression with the unary test `-v myvariable` tests wether the variable `myvariable` has been set. Note that `myvariable` should not be expanded by prefixing it with a dollar, so **not** `$myvariable`.
Now I find that for array elements the conditional expression `-v myarray[index]` works well too, without the full expansion syntax `${myarray[$index]}`. Try this:

```
    myarray[2]=myvalue
    for i in 1 2 3
    do
        [ -v myarray\[i] ] && echo element $i is set
    done
```

(note the escape `\[` to prevent globbing, as alternative to using quotes)

gives the desired output:

```
    element 2 is set
```

**Question**
Is this behaviour safe to use *aka* is this documented behaviour?

**Addendum**
After reading the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/677920/376817 of Stéphane Chazelas, I expanded my example:

```
    myarray[1]=val myarray[2]=val myarray[3]=val myarray[4]=val myarray[5]=val myarray[6]="" myarray[2]=""
    unset myarray[3] myarray[4] myarray[5]
    touch myarray4 myarrayi
    myarray4=val myarrayi=val
```

then

```
    for i in {0..7}; do [ -v myarray\[i] ] && echo element $i is set; done
```

gives

```
    element 1 is set
    element 2 is set
    element 6 is set
```

Without quoting or escaping the index expression `[i]` :

```
    for i in {0..7}; do [ -v myarray[i] ] && echo element $i is set; done
```

gives

```
    element 0 is set
    element 1 is set
    element 2 is set
    element 3 is set
    element 4 is set
    element 5 is set
    element 6 is set
    element 7 is set
```

The same with the variable `myarrayi` unset :

```
    unset myarrayi
    for i in {0..7}; do [ -v myarray[i] ] && echo element $i is set; done
```

gives

```
    %nothing%
```

And finally with expansion of the index as `$i` (still without quoting or escaping the bracket) :

```
    for i in {0..7}; do [ -v myarray[$i] ] && echo element $i is set; done
```

it gives

```
    element 1 is set
    element 2 is set
    element 4 is set
```

because

```
    ls -l myarray*
```

shows

```
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 me us 0 nov 17 15:37 myarray4
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 me us 0 nov 17 15:37 myarrayi
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `bash`, you can do:

```
[ -v 'a[2]' ]
```

or

```
[[ -v a[2] ]]
```

To test whether the array element of index 2, or the associative array element of key "2" is set (even if that's to an empty string), but note:

- When using the `[` (aka `test`) command, you need to quote the `[` and `]` characters as they are globbing operators. Since `[` is just an ordinary command, it's interpreted like any other ordinary command, so the `a[2]` in `[ -v a[2] ]` would be expanded the same way as it would in `ls -d a[2]` or `unset a[2]`. If there was a file called `a2` in the current working directory, `a[2]` would expand to that. And if there wasn't but the `nullglob` or `failglob` was enabled `a[2]` would expand to nothing or give an error respectively. `[[ ... ]]` is a special construct with its own syntax so wouldn't have the problem.
- For associative arrays (at least in version 5.1 which I tested this on), if the key to check is in a `$i` variable, you'd want `[ -v 'a[$i]' ]` or `[[ -v 'a[$i]' ]]` and the `assoc_expand_once` option introduced in newer versions of `bash` **not** to be enabled. Using <strike>`[ -v "a[$i]" ]`</strike> or <strike>`[[ -v a[$i] ]]`</strike> wouldn't work for some values of `$i` containing `]` or backslashes. There, it's the `$` that must be quoted. See also [How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627474).
- Still for associative arrays, note that `bash` (contrary to `ksh93` which `bash` attempted to copy or `zsh`) doesn't support the empty keys. If you use `[[ -v 'a[$i]' ]]` and `$i` is the empty string, you'd get an error. So to test for arbitrary key values, use `[[ -n $i && -v 'a[$i]' ]]` or `[ -n "$i" ] && [ -v 'a[$i]' ]`.
- For normal (sparse) arrays, in `[ -v 'a[expr]' ]` or `[[ -v a[expr] ]]`, `expr` is evaluated as an arithmetic expression. That's why both `i` and `$i` work. Since arithmetic expression can have side effects of assigning variables or running arbitrary commands, it's important that the value of `$i` used in `[ -v 'a[i]' ]` be sanitised or otherwise you have an arbitrary command execution vulnerability. As seen at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346), the fact the `bash`'s `[ -v lvalue ]` works for array indices makes things like `[ -f $file ]` (where the author forgot to quote `$file`) an ACE vulnerability.
- in any case, you can always use the Bourne/POSIX method (`[ -n "${var+set}" ]`) applied to the (associative) array element: `[ -n "${a[$key]+set}" ]` which doesn't need any work around and works with all versions of bash with array support (2.0 (1996) or above) or associative array support (4.0 (2009) or above) and is portable across shells with those.
- note that `[ -v var ]` is actually the same as `[ -v 'var[0]' ]`. Like in ksh88, scalar variables can be seen as the element of index 0 of an array.
- to check whether an array or associative array has any element (or that a scalar variable be set), you can also do `[ "${#a[@]}" -gt 0 ]` or `[ -v 'a[@]' ]` or `[ -v 'a[*]' ]`. **2023 edit**, as [noted by @johnraff](/a/742451), those last two no longer work for associative array since version 5.2 unless you enable 5.1 compatibility.
- to loop over the indices of sparse arrays or keys of associative arrays, you can do:

  ```
  for key in "${!a[@]}"; do
    printf 'The element of key "%s" is set\n' "$key"
  done
  ```

  (that gives `0` for a scalar variable).

As to whether that's documented: if you run `info bash test` or `info bash '['`, you'll [see](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-test) that it defers to [Bash conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) (as used inside `[[ ... ]]`), where the documentation of `-v` has:

> `-v VARNAME`
> True if the shell variable VARNAME is set (has been assigned a
> value).

While `help test` has:

> ```
>  -v VAR         True if the shell variable VAR is set.
> ```

What `VARNAME` may be (in particular if array members are allowed) or what it does if `VARNAME` refers to a variable that is not a scalar variable is not clearly specified. But given that `a[x]` is generally allowed wherever a variable name is expected and that it's been the case for decades, we can probably safely assume it will remain the case in the future.

If you look at other sections of that official documentation, you'll see that it's generally implied that wherever a variable name is expected (whether it's referred to as *NAME*, *VAR*, *VARNAME* or more generally *PARAMETER*), `varname[index]` is also accepted. For instance, in the documentation of `unset` itself ([`info bash unset`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-unset)), there's no mention of `unset 'array[i]'`, but it is mentioned in [the section about arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

The [`NEWS`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-5.1#n795) file in the source distribution (the release notes) tells us that `test -v` was added in bash-4.2 (2011), likely inspired from ksh93 which added it not long before in ksh93t+ (2009, with array element support mentioned in its own release notes)

> f.  `test`/ `[` / `[[` have a new `-v` variable unary operator, which returns success if `variable' has been set.

And in 4.3:

> ll. The `test` / `[` / `[[` `-v variable` binary operator now understands array references.

In 5.1:

> x. `test -v N` can now test whether or not positional parameter N is set.

You'll find that `CWRU/changelog` in the source distribution has some  mentions of `test -v array[@]` or `[[ -v array[$key] ]]` for associative arrays, hinting again at the fact that the feature is intentional.

It's not impossible that some things could be done in the future to address some of the problems mentioned above which could invalidate the work arounds I mention such as needing to quote `$`.

Comment: Good remark on quoting the operand of `-v`. I reran my example with a file `myarrayi`, and a variable `myarrayi` set or unset, and the globbing occurs as you say. I edited the example. Also thanks for explaining why `myarray[$i]` gives the same result as `myarray[i]`. But do you answer my question? You say that my code works; I tested it, so I knew that. But is it documentated that the `-v` unary operator also works on the `name[index]` construct, and not only on a simple `name`? I do not like to use undocumented features. That is my question, that I feel you do not answer.

Comment: I see you edited your answer to try to address my question, while I was writing my previous comment. I still hope someone may know of relevant documentation elsewhere.

Comment: @db-inf. The `info` book is the official documentation (you can also find it in other formats derived from the same source like the HTML one I linked). Ultimately, you can look at the source to see how it's done and see if the behaviour is intentional or an accident of implementation that may go away in the future. In any case, Chet Ramey will decide whether to keep it in the future or not, whether it's documented or not. As it's not clearly documented, he could decide to drop it, but that would upset a number of users. So most likely, you'd still be able to use BASH_COMPAT=5.1 to use it then.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that

Comment: I followed your advice, and dived into the source code at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/bash/. Most of the code for the `-v` unary test turns out to be for array checking. So yes, it is on purpose that ` -v 'myarray[i]'` gives the result as is. However, between my current version 4.4(.18) and the most recent 5.1.8 there has been a lot of change to the code: it is not stable yet, and the lack of detailed documentation may be a consequence thereof.

Comment: I might add that in the 5.1.8 code, it is very clear that `-v 'myarray[@]'` and `-v 'myarray[@]'` return true when any array element is set. I tested it in 4.4.18 and it works as such, but to me that is not clear from a quick look at the code.
Also, new in the 5.1.8 code is that it allows to test for the positional parameters as well: `-v 1` tests wether positional parameter 1 (that elsewhere you refer to as `$1`) is set. I tested that in my bash 4.4.18, and it does **not** work.

Comment: @db-inf, that reminds me I saw `test -v 1` mentioned in the release notes. See edit for more there.

Comment: Thanks for digging up the link to the NEWS document. I feel that answers my question sufficiently.

Answer (score 2):

With bash 5.2 it is no longer possible to test whether an associative array contains any elements with `test -v 'arr[@]'`, which now tests for a key specifically named '@'.

I guess `test "${#arr[@]}" -gt 0` or `(( ${#k[@]} > 0 ))` will do instead.

See compat51: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Compatibility-Mode