data json to env unix with jq
i have problem my command for me is working but the command export test=test not working in command with jq but if i run only export test=test it's working
so i have file test.json inside :
{ "test":"test124","url":"google.com"}

so i use this command :
jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\(.value)"' test.json | sh

i check in env i see nothing
i try this command :
jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)"' test.json | while IFS='=' read -r key value; do export "$key=$value"; ; done

same problem
but if i put this command is working :
export test=$(jq -r .test test.json)

but i want i loop :/
thx for help
SOLUTION :
missing $(...)
 $(jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\(.value)"' test.json)



Ok i find solution
i missing $(..)
so solution :
$(jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\(.value)"' test.json)```

No, that's not a solutions. Try it with a value that contains a space and at least one literal double quote.

The main issue in your initial attempts is that you set the environment variables in some other environment (the environment of the started sh shell in the first instance and the environment of the sub-shell that runs the while loop in the other instance).  The environment and your variables are removed when that shell or sub-shell terminates.
Given some simple JSON file like this one:
{
  "test": "test124",
  "url": "google.com",
  "other": "some \"other\" 'value'"
}

... we can create a shell script fragment that exports each key as an environment variable with the given (decoded) string value:
jq -r 'to_entries | map_values(@sh "export \(.key)=\(.value)")[]' file

or, a tiny bit shorter,
jq -r 'with_entries(.value = @sh "export \(.key)=\(.value)")[]' file

The @sh operator in jq tries to do the right thing with the given string, producing a hopefully valid quoted shell string.
With my example JSON document above, this would generate
export 'test'='test124'
export 'url'='google.com'
export 'other'='some "other" '\''value'\'''

This could be evaluated in a shell using eval (note the double-quoted command substitution; we need to preserve whitespaces in the output from jq):
eval "$( jq -r 'to_entries | map_values(@sh "export \(.key)=\(.value)")[]' file )"

Then...
$ printf '%s\n' "$test" "$url" "$other"
test124
google.com
some "other" 'value'

Note that this does not check the validity of the variable names. However, it supports variables containing newlines and will also preserve other whitespace characters.
You can construct JSON strings that can't be converted to valid string values in the shell in all locales though, and there are security issues with this sort of approach in general.  See e.g. the related answer from Stéphane Chazelas
here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681375/116858

Or jq -r 'to_entries[] | @sh "export \(.key)=\(.value)"'. Are there any benefits in using one or the other?

There are additional security concerns In this instance, because one of the quoted strings is interpreted as an lvalue by the shell and a[arithmetic-expression] is a valid lvalue in several shells (and is still interpreted as such even for export where that makes less sense in zsh and some implementations/versions of ksh), and the interpretation of that arithmetic expression can run commands. For instance echo '{"test[1\uname>&2`]":"x"}' | jq -r 'to_entries | map_values(@sh "export (.key)=(.value)")[]' | zshdoes rununame`.

@StéphaneChazelas Re you 1st: No benefits. Tomato, tomato.
