# Delete repeating file name based on dates

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have thousand of files that look like this.

- wrfout_d03_2010-06-11_00:00:01
- wrfout_d03_2010-06-11_00:00:08
- wrfout_d03_2010-06-12_00:00:20
- wrfout_d03_2010-06-12_00:00:35
- wrfout_d03_2010-06-12_00:00:40

I need to keep only the first timestamp. In this case,

- wrfout_d03_2010-06-11_00:00:01
- wrfout_d03_2010-06-12_00:00:20

may I know to do this without deleting this one by one? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -A seen=()
for f (wrfout_d*(N)) (( seen[\${f%_*}]++ )) && echo rm -f $f
```

(remove the `echo` if happy with the result)

A `bash` equivalent (assuming bash 4.0 or newer) would look like:

```
(shopt -s nullglob
typeset -A seen=()
for f in wrfout_d*; do
   (( seen[\${f%_*}]++ )) && echo rm -f "$f"
done)
```

Glob expansions are sorted lexically, so with you timestamp format, that does coincide with chronological order. So above we're looping over the files from oldest to youngest and remove the file if the name stripped of the shortest trailing `_*` (`${f%_*}`) has already been seen (as recorded in the `$seen` `A`ssociative array. For the reason behind the `\` in the arithmetic expression, see [How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627474)

Answer (score 2):

```
prev=
for file in wrfout_d*_*_*; do
  head=${file%_*}
  if [ "$head" = "$prev" ]; then
    # Remove "echo" if output is correct
    echo rm -f -- "$file"
  else
    prev=$head
  fi
done
```

The part of the filename before the last underscore is taken as the `head` variable. `echo rm` is reached when `head` is the same string as `prev`, otherwise `prev` is set to the value of `head`.

Answer (score 0):

An admittedly brittle solution that uses bash arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

workdir='/home/haxiel/testdir'
prefixes=( $(ls $workdir | cut -d '_' -f 1-3 | sort | uniq) )

for prefix in ${prefixes[@]}; do
files=( $workdir/$prefix* )
unset files[0]
echo rm -- ${files[@]}
done
```

I'm using the `ls|cut|sort|uniq` pipe to build a list of unique prefixes.

Then I loop through the prefixes and use shell globbing to grab all files that match a certain prefix and store it in an array. You want to keep the first one, so I remove that file from the array and pass the rest to an `rm` command.

This solution assumes that you have filenames without special characters. It also assumes that the shell's sort order matches your expected sort order.

Be sure to put the script outside of the working directory. Otherwise, the script name gets captured as one of the prefixes.

Run this once and examine the output to make sure that you're removing the right files. Then, remove the 'echo' command in front of `rm` and run it once again.

As always, data removal is a risky process, so use caution and have a backup if you think you'll need it.